# Alamofire deprecated code

Tags: swift, alamofire, nserror

Scenario: Networking app based on Alamofire.

I'm encountering deprecated-code notices in my latest project build.  I traced it to the following statement within Alamofire.  I don't see any mention of the alternatives.

```
@available(*, deprecated=3.4.0)
    public static func errorWithCode(code: Int, failureReason: String) -> NSError {
        let userInfo = [NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: failureReason]
        return NSError(domain: Domain, code: code, userInfo: userInfo)
    }
```

What's the replacement? 
And... how do I determine other replacements of deprecated codes?

Answer (score 0):

You now need to build your own errors with your own custom domain. It was unwise of us to originally expose those convenience methods because it led users to create their own errors using the Alamofire error domain which is not correct.

All of this is going to be easier in Swift 3 with the new AFError type being introduced.